# Why does the pickup gameObject inherit the player scale?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For my FPS 3D game, I have a `gameObject` (named pickupParent) which is a child of the main camera.

[image]

As its name suggests, it is for the picked-up objects to be placed in. However, the picked-up objects inherits the scale of the player. For example, when the player is crouching and picks up an object and then stands up, the object gets stretched and becomes taller!
How would I prevent that from happening?

Here is my code for the picking up objects:

```
 public void PickupObject()
        {
        physicsObject = lookObject.GetComponentInChildren<PhysicsObjects>();
        currentlyPickedUpObject = lookObject;
        pickupRB = currentlyPickedUpObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
       /* priorConstraints = pickupRB.constraints;    // <--- NEW
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeAll;    // <--- NEW*/
        pickupRB.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        physicsObject.playerInteractions = this;
        pickupRB.isKinematic = true;
        pickupRB.transform.parent = PickupParent.transform;
        //  StartCoroutine(physicsObject.PickUp());
    }
```

I want the picked-up object to always maintain its scale. How would I do that?

Comment: Because you parent it

Comment: but I need it to be a child of the camera so the object is floating in front of the player.

Comment: since my game is First Person. it needs to be like this

Comment: That’s fine. You need to adjust so that it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/691619/make-gameobject-a-child-without-affecting-scale.html) in Unity Forums. As Ed Unity says, your gameObject (pickupParent) will change its localScale relative to its parents (Camera and ThePlayer), so any changes in the scale of that objects, will affect their respective childs. You'll need to adjust the localScale of pickupParent in runtime.

An example for that is the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Borrar : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform parent = null;
    
    void Start()
    {
        parent = transform.parent;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 / parent.localScale.x,1 / parent.localScale.y,1/ parent.localScale.z);
    }
}
```

Note that in this example, scaling up/down will move the child away/closer from its parent.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks. but I have a question. my pickup method is in Update(), so should I add the line inside it or just in Update() ?

Comment: @SSS You may add it in the Update() method of a script attached to pickupParent, but it may cause some performance issues. Besides, I didn't test the example with multiple parents, my bad

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue for so long, I'm so close to giving up :/ it didn't work now it is not allowing me to pick up objects at all and it is throwing NullReferenceException error.